# Why is the output of the Embedding layer so non-linear?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have 2 nets, i.e. `net1` (i.e. `LinearLayer`) and `net2` (i.e. `EmbeddingLayer`) as below, while the input are just integers from 1 to 10:-

```
net1 = NetChain[{LinearLayer[2, "Input" -> 1]}];
net1 = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[10]; NetInitialize[net1]];
input = {#} & /@ Range[10];
output = net1[input];
ListLinePlot[output]
```

[image]

```
net2 = NetChain[{EmbeddingLayer[2, 100]}];
net2 = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[10]; NetInitialize[net2]];
input = Range[10];
output = net2[input];
ListLinePlot[output]
```

[image]

As you can see, `net1` is linear, while `net2` is obviously non-linear. But why `net2` is not linear? What is the mathematics behind `EmbeddingLayer`? Is `EmbeddingLayer` also using the linear operation $y=A W + B$ or not?

Many thanks!

Comment: My guess is that it encodes the integers with one-hot encoding and given random initial weight matrix it should behave like this.

Comment: Have a look in the 'Properties and Relations' section of `EmbeddingLayer` and `LinearLayer` to understand what they are computing. It should be clear then.

Comment: Thanks, that of `EmbeddingLayer` make it clear.